# add some char to field until x field length MYSQL

Tags: mysql

let say i try this query

```
select field1 from table1;
```

`field1` is integer and return result like this :

```
field1
---------
1
2
10
500
```

but i want to add zero until `field1` is 3 char lengths like this

```
field1  
----------
001     
002
010
500
```

for temporary i use this

```
select if(field1<10,concat('00',field1),if(field1<100,concat('0',field1),field1)) from table1
```

do mysql have function for that? can i have shorter query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [LPAD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

```
select LPAD(field1, 3, '0')
from table1
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/17444)